# Cant rm folder with GIT rm?

Tags: git, git-rm

I want to remove an entire directory with GIT ... each time I keep getting the same error and don't understand why this is happening.

I want to remove the "blue_white" folder ...

```
├── css
│   ├── design.css
│   └── red_white.css
├── images
│   ├── blue_white
│   │   ├── accordion-button.png
│   │   ├── accordion-shadow.png
│   │   ├── button1.png
│   │   ├── oem-slide-shadow.png
│   │   └── truncate-arrow.png
│   └── red_white
│       ├── accordion-shadow.png
└── pages.xml
```

When I do this ...

```
git rm -r blue_white/
```

I get this ...

```
fatal: pathspec 'f04/blue_white/' did not match any files
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. `$ rm -r images/blue_white/`
2. `$ git rm -r images/blue_white/`
3. `$ git commit -m 'Remove images/blue_white directory'`

Comment: Do you want to completely remove `images/blue_white/` directory or just take it out from git control?

Comment: Still getting the same problem in step 2 (git rm -r images/blue_white/)
Error: `fatal: pathspec ...........`

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are in the `f04` directory, not the `images` directory.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
git rm -r --cached blue_white
```

Then do a commit.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that `git rm` deletes a directory when the last remaining file is removed.

With only `myFile` residing in `myDir`, after performing
`git rm myDir/myFile`
directory `myDir` was gone. Note that I didn't use the `-r` option.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do this in a single step:

```
git rm -rf $parent_dir
```

After that, the directory and all its contents (subdirectories and files) are deleted, and `git status` also shows that `deleted: $parent_dir_files` is ready to be committed.